# doctrine2 (symfony2) many-to-many with "WITH" and null values

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, left-join, with-statement

I'm using Symfony2 Framework and having some trouble with a Doctrine database query:

I have defined two Entitys "customer" and "modules" and setup a many-to-may relationship between both. actualy modules are only stored to database if they are activated for the customer.

Image data base looks like this:

```
Customer
|id|name|
100, foobar
200, foobar2
300, foobar3

Modul
|id|name|
1, modul1
2, modul2
3, modul3
4, modul4

(automatic generated m-to-n table)
Customer_Modul
|customer_id|modul_id|
100, 1
200, 2
200, 4
300, 4
```

Now I want to query a specific customer and its modules. I need a left join, because modules are only stored if they are actived.

My query code looks like this:

```
$query = '
     SELECT m.id, m.name, CASE WHEN c.id IS NULL THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END as active
            FROM MyNamespace:Modul m
            LEFT JOIN m.customers c WITH c.id = :id
   ';

   $queryObj = $this->doctrine->getManager()->createQuery($query);
   $queryObj->setParameter('id', $id);
   $modules = $queryObj->getResult();
```

My Problem now is the following: Internally this native Query is made by doctrine:

```
SELECT 
  m0_.id AS id0, 
  m0_.name AS name1, 
  CASE WHEN c1_.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS sclr2 
FROM 
  modul m0_ 
  LEFT JOIN customer_modul c2_ ON m0_.id = c2_.modul_id 
  LEFT JOIN customer c1_ ON c1_.id = c2_.customer_id 
  AND (c1_.id = ?)
```

But the native query i actually need is this one:

```
SELECT 
  m0_.id AS id0, 
  m0_.name AS name1, 
  CASE WHEN c1_.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS sclr2 
FROM 
  modul m0_ 
  LEFT JOIN customer_modul c2_ ON m0_.id = c2_.modul_id 
  AND (c2_.customer_id = ?)
  LEFT JOIN customer c1_ ON c1_.id = c2_.customer_id
```

Has anybody an idea how to do this except using a native doctrine query?

Thanks you already for your help,

Susa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, 
    (SELECT c.id FROM YourNamespace:Customers c JOIN c.modules m2 
     WHERE m2.id = m.id and c.id = :customerId) AS checked
FROM YourNamespace:Modul m
```

Comment: seems to be a small hack, but worked for me. thanks!